# How to compile only app.js and skip vendor packages with lavarel mix?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

When do `npm run dev` it recompile all vendor packages with my small app.js. On my local it takes 30 seconds and will take more when I add more packages...

Is it possible to keep vendor packages and compile only app.js?

Another words... I want to recompile vendor.js only when something changed in packages.

my mix:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .extract()
    .version();
```

responce

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 31089ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                       11:42:58 AM

          Asset      Size        Chunks             Chunk Names
   /css/app.css   177 KiB       /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
     /js/app.js  24.8 KiB       /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
/js/manifest.js  6.12 KiB  /js/manifest  [emitted]  /js/manifest
  /js/vendor.js  1.95 MiB    /js/vendor  [emitted]  /js/vendor
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which libraries should be extracted. Then you will get `vue.js` and a `manifest.js` in the output folder. You have to include `manifest.js` in all pages as well.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .extract(['vue']) //like this
    .version();
```

Comment: `.extract()` extract all packages to vendor.js. And your answer have no sense, because `nmp run dev` will still compile all again. I need that vendor.js NOT recompile every time.